# Export data from Hive to AWS Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, hive, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I'm trying to export 1TB of hive data using hive -e as we dont have option to access hdfs file system and load the data to Redshift . The data has been exported in multiple small files like 30000+ small PARQUET files sums upto 1TB of data. To load the data into redshift it is throwing a error

```
String contains invalid or unsupported UTF8 codepoints. Bad UTF8 hex sequence: e9 (error 2)
```

Options Tried:

1. ACCEPTINVCHARS -- which is not available for parquet format
2. Try to load using Athena -> Glue cralwer -> Redshift . Not straightforward solution as we have to do the same in 40+ tables in hive.

How to build a pipeline to copy the data from Hive and load into Redshift . S3 load also can be skipped.

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/a/68810546/4326922

Answer (score 0):

I've held off on answering since I'm not a Hive expert.  The issue is the character encoding of the files.  Redshift uses multi-byte UTF8 (like most of the internet) and these files are encoded differently (likely UTF16 coming from Windows, but that is just a guess).  I believe that Hive can operate on both of these character sets (by configuring the SerDe but again I'm not a Hive expert).  What I don't know is if Hive can read in one encoding and export in another.

When I have used Hive it has preserved the input encoding to the output.  So one option would be to change the file encodings to UTF8 from the source system feeding Hive.  In the past I've done this from mySQL - export from mySQL in UTF8 and feed through Hive to Redshift.  This is the easiest approach as it is just configuring a step that already exists.

Another approach is to convert the files from one encoding to the other.  the Linux command iconv does this or you could write some code for a Lambda.  This step could be inserted before or after Hive.  You will need to know the current file encoding which should be in the file BOM.  You can read this with the Linux command 'file '.

As I said above if Hive can do the conversion that would be great.  I just don't know if it does this.

Bottom line - The issue is with the file encodings that Hive is running upon.  These need to be changed to UTF8 for Redshift.  This can be done at the source system, with a conversion tool, or possibly in Hive.

If you want to know a lot more on the subject see: https://github.com/boostcon/cppnow_presentations_2014/blob/master/files/unicode-cpp.pdf